# Grub does not load up even after running boot-repair

Tags: grub2, windows, windows-8

I had a successfully running computer with dual booting Windows 8 and Ubuntu 13.04 until I made the drastic decision to upgrade Windows 8 to 8.1.

The upgrade to Windows 8.1 was fine but I discovered that Grub was not loading.

So using a live CD I managed to run boot-repair to repair the EFI partition (just like when I first installed Ubuntu about few months ago).

However this time even after running boot-repair with recommended settings, Windows 8.1 keeps booting rather than Grub.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Turn off `secure boot` and run `boot-repair`.